# Formating email sent from android to any domain

Tags: android, html, email, formatting, cross-domain

I have successfully send email to **Gmail** domain (for example: usename@gmail.com). The email content is HTML. That means it is something like(a very rough example with variables decided at runtime):

```
"<html>" + "<head></head>"
                    + "<body bgcolor = \"#ffffff\">"
                    + "<h3>MOTOR CLAIM INTEMATION</h3>" + "<table>" + "<tr>"
                    + "<td>Policy No:</td>" + "<td><strong>"
                    + policyn
                    + "</strong></td>"
                    + "</tr>"
                    + "<tr>"
                    + "<td>Vehicle No:</td>"
                    + "<td><strong>"
                    + vehicleno
                    + "</strong></td>"
                    + "</tr>"
                    + "<tr>"+ "</table>" + "<body>" + "</html>";
```

This is very much formatted at gmail domain. But once I send this exact email content to other domain, **I get plain text** (**without HTML tags and no formating**).

[image: Formatted that is sent to @gmail.com]
[image: Not formatted sent to other domain]

What is the problem here? What should be done?

Thank you!!

Comment: I don't know how you send the email to the user. But in .net when you send a mail there a property called isHtmlContent and you have to set it to true so the mail will be interpreted as html. They might be a way to specify that the email is html content.

Comment: yes i have used it here as well. That is the reason why i am getting formatted for gmail domain. @MathieuLabrieParent Thank you

Comment: I know that email handle very restricted html. It's really a pain to format you email in a way that every email platform will correctly display your content. Good luck.

Comment: @MathieuLabrieParent Would love to hear what you want to say. :-)

Comment: I already done this in the past. I make it fit on outlook, gmail and hotmail. The table layout is definatively the easiest way to have a clean layout. Your on the right way.

Comment: @MathieuLabrieParent But haven't been ok for some other account

Comment: Have been ok for every account. I never check if there a setting somewhere on the client that say : Never interpreted mail as html. Maybe it's just a client setting problem.